# How does tensorflows's session.run's fetch argument can be an output of another function, without declaring that output's name as a placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code that I have simplified:

```
class someClass():
 def __init__(self):
   self.u_pred, self.v_pred = self.fnc(self.x_tf, self.y_tf)
   self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                                     log_device_placement=True))
   def predict(self, x, y):
    
     tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x, self.y_tf: y}
    
     u = self.sess.run(self.u_pred, tf_dict)
     v = self.sess.run(self.v_pred, tf_dict)
     return u, v
```

Here how does sess.run able to fetch `self.u_pred` and `self.v_pred` when they are not even part of the graph as they havent been declared using `tf.placeholder`?
After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126143/example-or-explanation-for-tensorflows-session-run-feed-dict-method-what-does) question, my understanding is that session calls the `tf.placeholder` and fetches the first argument passed and evaluates with the dictionary provided.

So in this case does `self.sess.run(self.u_pred, tf_dict)` able to automatically find `self.fnc()` and plugs in `tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x, self.y_tf: y}` to auto-evaluate the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF graphs are frozen when you first create the session. Most [tensorflow function *definitions* within a graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py) experience this event. As soon as this event happens, you are enabled to add new or existing functions. After you do this process, the new or existing functions (you added) become frozen too. [Note you may be using an outdated version of tf](https://that%20has%20deprecated%20functions). This is significant as [tf workflows may change after each major tf release](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#1_replace_v1sessionrun_calls), given that some tf functions may get deprecated.

Comment: can you please elaborate  what does `function definitions experience this event` mean?

Comment: so does `self.sess.run(self.u_pred, tf_dict)` able to automatically find `self.fnc()`?

Comment: Also frozen in my understanding means that all the state of variables, hyperparameters being `frozen` as part of the graph's latest epoch (currently not trainalbe). But how does this it relates to my quetion of how TF graph is able to access output of a function that has not been declared as part of the graph before using `placeholders`

Comment: @user_04248753498 i wrote `function definitions within a graph experience this event` not `function definitions experience this event`. The graph portion is key. I am not sure epochs have anything to do here since you cannot dynamically add new functions during training/fitting to my knowledge. Other relevant information is in the source code link I included in my answer. If you think I answered your original question, please upvote or mark it as the answer. Other follow  up questions are excellent candidates for future questions to the community.

Comment: ok, but i appreciate if you could elaborate your answer a bit so I have better clarity on this.

Comment: @user_04248753498 ok. As long as it is related to the original question, let me know the specific area you want more clarity on.

Comment: I want to know whats the relevance of "graphs being frozen" in this context. I know what it means but with reference to my question why have you highlighted this? if you can elaborate on this point only that shall be great!

Comment: @user_04248753498 frozen because tf definitions and operations are [added to the graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph). They are not executed `eagerly`. I suggest you go thru the source code and docs for the version of tf you are using. i checked your code again. You may be [using an outdated tf that has deprecated functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session) that changes tf workflows comprared to recent tf versions. If you have an outdated PC, kaggle and similar services give you basic but free options to run notebooks with the latest tf.